# android listview swipe to delete like in gmail app

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

Show to implement ListView like in gmail APP when the swipe effect on item deletes it?
I have tried using ViewPager as ListView element but this does not work.

Thanks

Comment: None of the answers in the linked question have been accepted.  How can you say this has an answer already?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Roman Nurik from the Android Developer Team created a SwipeToDismiss Listener you can implement, it is open sourced <s>[here](https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/source/browse/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/ui/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java)</s>.

---

**Edit**
project is available on this location now - https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss

Comment: Can you please help me out to get it implemented

Comment: How to use it? Any sample code?

Comment: It's right there in the comments line 49-63

Comment: The comment has a mistake however. It should create an instance of `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks` instead of `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.OnDismissCallback`

Comment: how could i implement for textview only instead of listview? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Also should note that "This class Requires API level 12 or later due to use of `{@link
 * android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator}`"

Comment: This link is dead now.  It is available on github:  https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss

Comment: I don't recommend this project now, as it's unmantained for 2 years as this comment is written