# using Set list adapter for +10000 rows

Tags: android, listview

If i use `SetListAdapter` to show +10,000 rows, may problems occur?

If yes, please guide me for choose a better way to show these rows.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, problems might occur. Why would you want the user to see that?

Comment: Problems can always occur, can you be more specific please?

Comment: 10,000 rows will cause problems with _any_ adapter.  You should never use that much data on one screen.  A much better solution would be to show only a few rows (20-30-whatever) with a "show more" option.

Comment: This is for a sms collection application,i'm a newbie ,sorry if ask a very regular question

Comment: @user2273788 have u ever seen any application on play-store  which has 10,000 items in list?

Comment: The point of the adapter in a list view is that only the visible views will be loaded at once, so assuming the dataset is also loaded sequentially then there will be no problem.

Comment: @ Pratik, no, but i haven't any experience in android programming,please guide me if possible

Comment: @user2273788 as u have mentioned it is for sms collection application i can give u some idea...u can fetch items as per the dates or say duration (last month,from date1 to date2,last week and so on)...and just display that many rows..it will be beneficial...if u want to check how this type of apps being managed then check "SMS Addict" application on play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` can display *any number* of elements data; but there is a trick when we're discussing about large and very large numbers: you need to re-use the views that the `ListView` is holding. This [Google IO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) presentation is the best thing I can recommend you.

Now, there are other things I can think of that will have a negative impact:

1. How much memory do those 10k object take? If it's an SMS collection, then 10k * 160 max chars per message * 4 bytes per char would give 6.4 million bytes which is ~6 Mb. Now 6 MB is not really that much to hold in memory but it's not a number you can neglect.
2. How fast accessible is an object in this store? If you hold this data structure in memory and you would store it as an `ArrayList` then I believe you would have instant access. Or decide for yourself what data structure to use. Seems to me choosing the right collection is really important. Maybe [this article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) will help you.

In the end you should also consider about how users will use the app. Would it worth storing all messages in memory since the user will probably want to see latest ones, the ones from last week, or the ones from his favorite contacts? Maybe a filtering option would be helpful to have and this way you could persist them in SQLite.

Comment: Thank you very much .Is it possible to load the rows gradually? for example,30 rows loaded,and when user arrived to the end of 30 rows ,then next 30 rows load

Comment: Try this article (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/) or use some sort of 3 party swipeable listview (https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367671/android-listview-swipe-to-delete-like-in-gmail-app)